# Vivado version difference first stage boot loader

Tags: fpga, vivado, zynq

I have a little problem and bug in Vivado 2016.1.
For my zynq (z-turn 7020) Vivado SDK is not able to compile a working first stage boot loader (compilation is not the problem only the .elf file is not working). However using an old 2014.4 or 2015.4 project with working fsbl is working in the BOOT image.
If I do not boot from sd card and use the project in the SDK directly it is working.

What are the exact differences between the .elf files from different SDK versions?
Are there any problems I run into if using old fsbl in newer projects for creating the boot.img?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you the differences between the versions of the fsbl, but if the old version is working there is really no need to build a newer version. We build one fsbl per type of board and never change it once it is working.

I would be much happier if fsbl sources were on github, to make it easier to answer this question.

You could run diff -urN on the source trees generated by the SDK, or check them into git (or other source control system) and compare them that way.